# Do Redeads stay dead?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

In Ocarina of Time, in the Castle Town Market after you are an adult, the Redeads will jump on you and kill you if you don't either run or kill them.

When they die, they collapse on the ground, but unlike other Zelda enemies, they don't disappear. Does this mean they could potentially get back up and kill me?

Comment: "This disease is called "Gingervitis". Kids who have Gingervitis cannot be cured." - Eric Cartman

Comment: Wow, it took me 10 minutes to realize it wasn't "Redheads".

Comment: Same here, which is why I dropped the quote. I thought Ashley just hated Redheads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't remember any of them getting up again, and according to [strategywiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Enemies#Royal_Family_Tomb), the corpse remains because the other ReDeads will walk there instead of trying to follow link (I actually never waited long enough to observe that).

You can make life much easier with ReDeads by playing the [Sun's Song](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Ocarina_Songs#Sun.27s_Song) when you enter a room with these fellows, since that causes them to freeze for a while.

Comment: Note that in Majora's Mask (which doesn't have the Sun's Song) you can equip the Captain's Mask, Gidbo Mask, or Garo Mask to make Redeads dance instead of attack you.

Answer (score 2):

The question is amusing in itself since they aren't called RE-deads for no reason.  They all respawn like most normal enemies.

IIRC, the Sun's Song won't keep them stunned forever, so if you're a bit edgy, you might want to just help them out of their misery so they won't come and attack you from behind when you're being all carefree (or careless :P)

Answer (score 0):

They do not come back to life after you kill them, aside from respawning like your typical enemy. They will, however.. lure other re-deads near by that crouch over top of the corpse as if it is morning the loss, then the corpse fades away into nothing.